# Repeater definition will be removed from designer in a nested repeater

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a nested repeater and every time I compile the project, VS automatically removes the declaration of the inner repeater from designer and I have to  manually add it again.

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater rptrSubscriptions;
```

I have deleted VS temp files and after reading other questions like mine, I also converted the page to web form.
Finally I changed the inner repeater to GridView, as I thought there may be a bug for nested repeater, but I still had the same problem.

For testing that the nested repeater works fine I added an empty repeater with the name of `repeater1`, and it works fine: it will not be removed at compile time.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<%--================================================================--%>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptionGroups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Width="950">
                <asp:TableRow CssClass="SolidBorder">
                    <%--SHow Subscriptions ( Left Side )--%>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="550">
//some source here
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <div class="">
                            <%--SHow Small TV+Radio Images--%>
                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgTVRadio" alt="" Style="width: 220px; height: 50px;" runat="server" OnCommand="SubscriptionGroup_Click" CommandName="SubscriptionClick" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"GroupName") %>' BorderStyle="None" />
                            </a>

                            <%-- ===========Test repeater that will not be removed from designer ====================================--%>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>

                            <%-- =========== repeater that will  be removed from designer ====================================--%>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptions_ItemCommand">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Table ID="Table2" class="NoBorderInTable" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Width="380px">
                                        <asp:TableRow CssClass="SolidBorder" Style="background-color: lightgray; border-color: white" Height="30px">

                                            <%--Show Radio Buttons--%>
                                            <asp:TableCell>
                                        <%--<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />--%>
                                        <input name="SubscriptionSelected" id="SubscriptionSelected" type="radio" value="1">
                                        <%--Focuses on the selected radio button--%>
                                        <script>
                                            $('#tableSelect tr').click(function () {
                                                $(this).find('th input:radio').prop('checked', true);
                                            })
                                        </script>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                    </asp:Table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                            <%--=====================================================================================================--%>
                        </div>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner Repeaters or any other server control shouldn't be in your designer. So if you change anything in your markup which triggers an update of the designer.cs it will remove all inner server controls.

A repeater will have multiple items most of the times (that's why you use a repeater). So if you have 10 items bound to your repeater, you won't get 10 inner repeaters in your designer. You won't get 1 inner repeater in your designer either, since that can't be used to control the 10.

You should access your inner repeater in your DataItemBound rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound. I always use the same name as the one I used in the markup so it's clear which you mean:

```
protected void rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args) {
    //Get the inner repeater in the current repeater-item
    Repeater rptrSubscriptions = args.Item.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions") as Repeater;
    if (rptrSubscriptions != null) {
        //Do what you need todo for this inner repeater
        rptrSubscriptions.DataSource = someSource; //args.Item.DataItem should be the DataSource-item you bound to rptrSubscriptionGroups so use that to sort your Source for the inner repeater
        rptrSubscriptions.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Decker, it was a great help and wise answer :) I really appreciate that.

Comment: Great to hear it helped! At least you are using repeaters. Learn these ways and you will find repeaters very useful and easy to use. May I also suggest you using server-side Table and TableCell is not adding anything since you won't need to access it server-side. Use html table and lose the overhead.